# access modifiers in Java - a recap

Tags: java, inheritance, protected, access-modifiers

I'm trying to understand what these modifiers really means, beacause I think there's a lot of confusion about what they do or don't do.
So, here's what I know:

four access modifiers are used:

`public` , `protected` , `private` , `no modifier(package private)`.

1) with respect to members inside its definition: a class can access every one of them no matter what the access modifier.

2) with respect to another class, which it doesn't inherit from nor shares the same package: it can access only members which are marked as `public`.

3) with respect to another class in the same package,but which it doesn't inherit from: it can access only members marked as `public` , `protected` and have `no modifier(package private)`.

now comes the tricky part (at least for me..)

4) if a class A inherits from another class B, but doesn't share the same package, A has all the members (fields and methods) declared `public` and `protected` in B. 
BUT with respect to AN INSTANCE of B, A can only access `public` members (not `protected` or `no modifier(package private)` ones, am I right on this??).

5) if a class A inherits from another class B, and they share the same package, A has all the members (fields and methods) declared `public` , `protected` AND `no modifiers(package private)`in B (am I right??).
Since A and B are in the same package, A is able to access `protected` , `no modifier(package private)` members of any instance of B (and of course `public` ones as well).

In addition, since A is-a B which members will another class (say, C) trying to access a member of A (of one of its instance of course, but let's keep it simple) be able to get to??
I know for sure C will be able to access `public` members, but what about `protected` , or `no modifier(package private)` ones in case 4 and 5? 
(I leave `private` aside, since those members can only be accessed inside the defining class)

please, help!

This is what happens in terms of access/inheritance :

```
package one;

//class with all kind of modifiers
public class A {

    protected void methodProtected(){}

    public void methodPublic(){}

    void methodDefault(){}

    private void methodPrivate(){}

}
```

---

```
//same package,no inheritance
package one;

public class B {

    {
        new A().methodDefault();
        new A().methodProtected();
        new A().methodPublic();
    }

}
```

---

```
//same package,inheritance
package one;

public class C extends A {

    {
        new A().methodDefault();
        new A().methodProtected();
        new A().methodPublic();
        methodDefault();
        methodProtected();
        methodPublic();
    }

}
```

---

```
//different package,inheritance
package two;
import one.A;

public class D extends A{

    {
        new A().methodPublic();
        A a = new A();
        //compiler error: can't access protected members
        //a.methodProtected();
        methodPublic();
        methodProtected();
    }

}
```

---

```
//different package,no inheritance
package two;
import one.*;

    public class E {

        {
            new A().methodPublic();

        }
    }
```

now, I would like to know what happens when E tries to access B,C or D,
and what if E inherits from A or one of the other classes, or is in the same package?? what a mess...

Comment: the best way to finding out answers to your questions would be just to write a program with all the cases, and see what the compiler says.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, what's the difference between public, default, protected, and private?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Comment: There's a further complexity of inner classes - an inner class can access the outer class's `private` variables and vice-versa.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private

Comment: Have a look at [this cheat sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052) and it should be clear. Let me know if you like me to clarify further.